# Why is Robinhood a second rate stock broker?

Tags: robinhood

I have heard that Robinhood is not the best fee free stock broker.

The issues I am aware of are that you can't buy fractional shares of stocks, and you can't day trade efficiently.

What other issues does Robinhood have?

Comment: If you remove the last question I would consider this on-topic. Also, where have you heard that it is "second rate"?

Comment: By now, nearly all of them are free, so the limited capabilities of Robinhood make it second tier. Robinhood did a great job to force them all to become free, but now it is not anything special anymore.

Comment: I don't understand why a request about the pros and cons of different brokerage firms is problematic.  Brokerage service, platform quality, tech support, commissions, margin, fees, etc. are all integral parts of investing.  In any event, per Nosjack's suggestion, II removed the request for recommendations.

Comment: @BobBaerker, asking for only the cons make it seem like this is meant to be a rant, or fuel for a rant, rather than a legitimate question.

Comment: @The Photon - You conclusion only makes sense if the OP and I are either the same person or we are acting in collusion to post a 'rant'.  Apart from assuring you that we are not one and the same, and assuring you  that I am not a ranter,  you can read the list of Robinhood deficiencies that I posted in my Answer and either read about RH on the net or try their app.  You'll come to the same conclusion.  RH is a second rate broker. Furthermore, if what I listed is true, how could it be a rant?  Facts are facts.  Cheers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Robinhood  had a perceived an edge when they were one of the few brokers that didn’t charge commissions.    I say perceived edge because they have many deficiencies.  Until recently they didn't pay interest on cash balances, they charge more for margin borrowing than other brokers, and they route orders for  [Payment For Order Flow](https://www.wsj.com/articles/why-free-trading-on-robinhood-isnt-really-free-1541772001) which can lead to poorer fills.  So effectively, they have one hand in your pocket while dangling a no commission carrot in front of you.

The drawbacks of Robinhood versus a discount broker? Here are many of many things that they lack:

- timely data
- good customer and tech support
- investment education
- interest on cash balances
- a platform that doesn't lock up
- research
- good charting
- prompt trade execution reports
- low margin rates
- portfolio margin
- good option analytics
- maker/taker rebates

Given that most of these services are available at major brokers who are now commission free, it makes no sense to trade at Robinhood. if you're a serious investor who needs better services and more than a stripped down platform, you should be trading elsewhere.

A few months ago, a Robinhood trader discovered a [GLITCH](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/do-not-try-this-at-home-how-to-turn-3000-into-17-million-2019-11-06) in their margin monitoring.  He used $3,000 to 
buy  more than $1.7 million in shares of Advanced Micro Devices while selling about $1.6 million in calls. IMO, Robinhood is a Mickey Mouse operation.

Comment: Multiple crashes at key times:  https://fortune.com/2020/03/09/robinhood-crash-third-time-stock-market/  Buggy portfolio display (manual refresh required to un-stick incorrect performance). Etc. If you're doing infrequent trading and simple/no option trading, then it's pretty much fine.

Comment: Just guessing but the elimination of commissions by  other brokers might have really hurt their new customer sign up rate. I think that their off ramp is selling to another broker.

Comment: Hey, don't disparage Mickey Mouse like that... Disney is no second rate operation!

Comment: Mea culpa.  My heartfelt apologies to Monsieur Mickey.