# What is a free or cheap Broker with Trading Software

Tags: stocks, brokerage, broker, day-trading, software

I am fairly new to trading. Recently I watched some videos after joining Robinhood and I realized that Robinhood is fairly limited.

I am looking for a broker company and software that allows me to do the following:

- Buy a stock
- Automatically set a stop loss price
- Automatically set a profit sell price
- No buy fee
- No sell fee

I am willing to pay small fee, if free is not available. Also if limit sell for free is available I will accept that too.

---

I found Ninjatrader does the automatic stop loss and sell, but it seems I cannot use it with Robinhood. This is why I need help because I cannot find a good mix of broker with a tool.

---

I plan to do very little day trading of stocks with scalping. I plan to buy and sell pretty quickly. I don't expect to become rich, hence why I need something affordable or free. Please help me.

I don't plan to trade options (if that helps)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIC, is a Mickey Mouse operation.  Here are the [reasons](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/123614/why-is-robinhood-a-second-rate-stock-broker/123620#123620) why.

Most of the major discount brokers no longer charge commissions (Ally, E*Trade, Interactive Brokers Lite, Merrill Edge, Schwab, TD Ameritrade, Vanguard). However, some charge fees, for example  65 cents per option trade which is tantamount to a commission.  All brokers pass through the small SEC fee when you sell a position.

The exchanges support buy and sell stop, limit and stop orders.  Some brokers offer many more types of algorithmic orders.

Each broker offers varying degrees of other services (charting, research, etc) so the best choices depends on your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I 100% agree about Robinhood being terrible. Based on what I posted above, which is mostly to stay cheap/free and have some algorithmic orders. Which do you recommend? I don't need to sell/buy options.

Comment: Interactive Brokers offers the most canned [algorithmic orders](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=4985)  that I know of.  For the tech savvy, it and a few others enable you to program your own but that's above my pay grade.  The Pro version has always been inexpensive (50 cent commission per 100 shares, minimum ticket $1) and there's a no commission Lyte version.  You'd have to go to their web site to see what the difference is.  Also, check out TradeStation. I don't know their fee structure but they're geared to  the DIY indicator/algoritmic trader.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry the question was closed. I appreciate your help